# Pinch/zoom with pointer events in Javascript clarification

Tags: javascript, pinchzoom, pointer-events

[The pinch/zoom example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events/Pinch_zoom_gestures) using `PointerEvent`s looks easy enough, yet looking a bit closer, I wonder about the following.

If two touching fingers are moved simultaneously with fixed distance, I assume the browser will generate interleaved pointer events for two different `PointerEvent.pointerId` values. When the software sequentially processes these events it looks as if the distance keeps flipping between two or three values, depending on how the events are delivered.

For example the x coordinates for the two pointers a and b could follow a sequence like a=0, b=100 for `pointerdown` and then `pointermove` events with a=3, b=103, b=106, a=6. If I compute the delta for each pointer move event, I get 97, 100, 103, 100 despite the user probably moving two fingers in parallel.

How is this done right? Do I need a minimal hold-off, like 10ms, for pointer events and batch them up before processing? Do I need a hysteresis of some kind?

This might be saner with touch events (didn't try), though I would really be interested in solutions based on pointer events. And I am interested in a plain Javascript algorithmic solution, though a pointer to a library that does it right accompanied by the gist of the solution would also be OK.